# How to unpickle a class that is linked with C,C++ and python in Java/Android?

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, serialization, pickle

I am using a Machine learning and statistical based classifier called as EVM (Extreme value machine) using link https://pypi.org/project/EVM/. I train the model in python and save it as pickle file with the below code.

```
import EVM
import pickle
mevm = EVM.MultipleEVM(tailsize=300, cover_threshold = 0.7, distance_multiplier = 0.7, distance_function = scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean)
mevm.train([trainX[i] for i in list(trainX.keys())])

#Save the trained model
with open('model.pkl','wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(mevm,f)
```

I could easily load the same model in Python using same Pickle module. When I save, all the weights gets saved inside the pickle file and I could do the inference as below,

```
import pickle
import EVM
with open('model.pkl','rb') as b:
     mevm = pickle.load(b)
print("Probability of given input", mevm.max_probabilities([embeds[i]]))
```

But I could not read the same pickle file in Android/Java (I want to use this saved model in my android application). When I check the EVM class, there is a C file and a C++ file which is connected using a '.pyx' file. All these 3 files are read using a python EVM (i.e. import EVM) class. Please refer to the below link for the files
https://pypi.org/project/EVM/#files

My questions are

1. How can I read this saved model in Android/Java ?
2. Since this is linked with C,C++ and python, will it be possible to read in Java ?
3. Any other better method to save this, so that I can use it Andriod/Java ?

Any leads are appreciated.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

According to python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

> The pickle module implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. “Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse operation, whereby a byte stream (from a binary file or bytes-like object) is converted back into an object hierarchy. Pickling (and unpickling) is alternatively known as “serialization”, “marshalling,” 1 or “flattening”; however, to avoid confusion, the terms used here are “pickling” and “unpickling”

This means that the given byte stream is only syntactically valid in Python only unless you want to write an object transpiler.

You are approaching your problem in the wrong way. ML model is just a set of coefficients/parameters that you have optimized to get a close approximation of your target variable. You should be able to take that set of coefficients/parameters and use it in any language.